# Applying multi processing and parallelism to numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, process, multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to parallelize on my numpy code to make it faster. The original numpy array `list_` has over 2 million variables so it is very hard to compute thats why I am trying to compute my calculations with numpy and multiprocessing functions. How could i utilize the code down below to work with multi processing units. I have a code below that i have tried with multi processing however I believe its not very efficient. Functions `ym, xym ,std` are independant so multi processing on those functions are doable however `mk,bk` are dependent on the `ym, xym ,std` functions.

Vanilla Python Version

```
import numpy as np
number = 5
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
ym = (np.convolve(list_, np.ones(shape=(number)), mode='valid')/number)[:-1]
xym = (np.convolve(list_, np.arange(number, 0, -1), mode='valid'))[:-1]
mk = (x_mean* ym- xym)/(np.power(x_mean,2)- x_squared_mean)
bk = ym - mk*x_mean
std = np.array([list_[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, len(list_)-number)])
```

Multi processing Version

```
#x_mean and x_squared is used for the lin regressions and stand dev
x_mean = number/2*(1 + number)
x_squared_mean = number*(number+1)*(2*number+1)/6

def ym():   
    ym = (np.convolve(PC_list, np.ones(shape=(number)), mode='valid')/number)[:-1]
    print(ym)
def xym():
    xym = (np.convolve(PC_list, np.arange(number, 0, -1), mode='valid'))[:-1]
    print(xym)
def std():
    std = np.array([PC_list[i:i+number].std() for i in range(0, len(PC_list)-number)])
    print(std)
    
#setting up the multi processing vars     
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=ym)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=xym)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=std)

#running the multi processes 
p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()

xym()
ym()
std()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mk` and `bk` are indeed dependent on `ym` and `xym`, there is nothing you can do, you will have to first compute those and then you can use them in the next calculations.

I did a quick benchmark and it looks like even if I have an array of 20 million, the convolutions, `mk` and `bk` all run under 0.3s. The real bottleneck in your code is the `std` function. That is because you are using the python `for` loop which is slow.

### Numba to the rescue

What I suggest is looking into [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/). It can compile your regular python functions into optimized machine code and make them run blazingly fast! It has some limitations, but for your case it would work perfectly. Try changing the `std` function to this:

```
from numba import njit

@njit 
def std_numba(x, n):
    std = np.array([x[i:i+n].std() for i in range(0, len(x)-n)])
    return std
```

Even without any kind of multiprocessing, all the computations ran in under a second on a random array of 2 million floats.

Comment: Thank you, for the effort I am having an issue installing the numba library on windows 10 at the moment, but I will test it out as soon as I can install it.